# If the classical Maxwell theory describes E&M fairly, how well-done is the classical Yang-Mills theory for chromodynamics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, classical-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills

If the classical Maxwell theory describes electrodynamics (electromagnetism E&M) fairly well, how suitable would the classical Yang-Mills theory (say SU(3) color) describe the chromodynamics, and how precisely?

I suppose the heavy quarks (c,t,b), being more non-relativistic and we can still heavily use the classical Yang-Mills theory? For light quarks, being relativistic, we may need to consider the classical Yang-Mills + relativistic Dirac equations, but would classical versions of Yang-Mills + relativistic Dirac theories and their Equations of Motions (EOMs) would be suitable to certain levels? How?

> p.s. This is a question concerning comparing the
>
> classical v.s. quantum  Maxwell/Yang-Mills theory.
>
> and how applicable are them to describe the real world:
>
> electrodynamics / chromodynamics.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you never see gluons in the wild, so you never have enough to make a classical field. I'm speculating at this point, but it might be interesting to see if a quark-gluon plasma might have some sort of classical description.

Comment: I'd say that (according to the numerical lattice computations) classical Yang-Mills theory *is not* the classical limit of the (strongly coupled) quantum Yang-Mills theory. That's why it is a bad approximation.

Answer (score 10):

This is nicely answered in Jaffe-Witten's "problem description" of the problem of [quantization of Yang-Mills theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantization+of+Yang-Mills+theory):

> By the 1950s, when Yang–Mills theory was discovered, it was already
>   known that the quantum version of Maxwell theory – known as Quantum
>   Electrodynamics or QED – gives an extremely accurate account of
>   electromagnetic fields and forces. In fact, QED improved the accuracy
>   for certain earlier quantum theory predictions by several orders of
>   magnitude, as well as predicting new splittings of energy levels.
>
> So it was natural to inquire whether non-abelian gauge theory
>   described other forces in nature, notably the weak force (responsible
>   among other things for certain forms of radioactivity) and the strong
>   or nuclear force (responsible among other things for the binding of
>   protons and neutrons into nuclei). The massless nature of classical
>   Yang–Mills waves was a serious obstacle to applying Yang–Mills theory
>   to the other forces, for the weak and nuclear forces are short range
>   and many of the particles are massive. Hence these phenomena did not
>   appear to be associated with long-range fields describing massless
>   particles.
>
> In the 1960s and 1970s, physicists overcame these obstacles to the
>   physical interpretation of non-abelian gauge theory. In the case of
>   the weak force, this was accomplished by the Glashow–Salam–Weinberg
>   electroweak theory with gauge group H=SU(2)×U(1). By elaborating the
>   theory with an additional “Higgs field”, one avoided the massless
>   nature of classical Yang–Mills waves. The Higgs field transforms in a
>   two-dimensional representation of HH; its non-zero and approximately
>   constant value in the vacuum state reduces the structure group from H
>   to a U(1) subgroup (diagonally embedded in SU(2)×U(1). This theory
>   describes both the electromagnetic and weak forces, in a more or less
>   unified way; because of the reduction of the structure group to U(1),
>   the long-range fields are those of electromagnetism only, in accord
>   with what we see in nature.
>
> The solution to the problem of massless Yang–Mills fields for the
>   strong interactions has a completely different nature. That solution
>   did not come from adding fields to Yang–Mills theory, but by
>   discovering a remarkable property of the quantum Yang–Mills theory
>   itself, that is, of the quantum theory whose classical Lagrangian is
>   the Yang-Mills Lagrangian. This property is called “asymptotic
>   freedom”. Roughly this means that at short distances the field
>   displays quantum behavior very similar to its classical behavior; yet
>   at long distances the classical theory is no longer a good guide to
>   the quantum behavior of the field.
>
> Asymptotic freedom, together with other experimental and theoretical
>   discoveries made in the 1960s and 1970s, made it possible to describe
>   the nuclear force by a non-abelian gauge theory in which the gauge
>   group is G=SU(3). The additional fields describe, at the classical
>   level, “quarks,” which are spin 1/2 objects somewhat analogous to the
>   electron, but transforming in the fundamental representation of SU(3).
>   The non-abelian gauge theory of the strong force is called Quantum
>   Chromodynamics (QCD).
>
> The use of QCD to describe the strong force was motivated by a whole
>   series of experimental and theoretical discoveries made in the 1960s
>   and 1970s, involving the symmetries and high-energy behavior of the
>   strong interactions. **But classical non-abelian gauge theory is very
>   different from the observed world of strong interactions**; for QCD to
>   describe the strong force successfully, it must have at the quantum
>   level the following three properties, each of which is dramatically
>   different from the behavior of the classical theory:
>
> (1) It must have a “mass gap;” namely there must be some constant
>   Δ>0  such that every excitation of the vacuum has energy at
>   least Δ.
>
> (2) It must have “quark confinement,” that is, even though the theory
>   is described in terms of elementary fields, such as the quark fields,
>   that transform non-trivially under SU(3), the physical particle states
>   – such as the proton, neutron, and pion -- are SU(3)-invariant.
>
> (3) It must have “chiral symmetry breaking,” which means that the
>   vacuum is potentially invariant (in the limit, that the quark-bare
>   masses vanish) only under a certain subgroup of the full symmetry
>   group that acts on the quark fields.
>
> The first point is necessary to explain why the nuclear force is
>   strong but short-ranged; the second is needed to explain why we never
>   see individual quarks; and the third is needed to account for the
>   “current algebra” theory of soft pions that was developed in the
>   1960s.
>
> Both experiment – since QCD has numerous successes in confrontation
>   with experiment – and computer simulations, carried out since the late
>   1970s, have given strong encouragement that QCD does have the
>   properties cited above. These properties can be seen, to some extent,
>   in theoretical calculations carried out in a variety of highly
>   oversimplified models (like strongly coupled lattice gauge theory).
>   But they are not fully understood theoretically; there does not exist
>   a convincing, whether or not mathematically complete, theoretical
>   computation demonstrating any of the three properties in QCD, as
>   opposed to a severely simplified truncation of it.